# ASP.Net GridView custom template not set on rows after postback

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I have a custom template column (ITemplate) for a GridView control.  This column is inserted/added into the GridView columns in the OnInit method of the GridView.  This appears to work fine and if I attempt to access the Rows of the grid in PreRender, I can see that each row has a cell of which the template field is my template column type.

```
((cell as DataControlFieldCell).ContainingField as TemplateField).ItemTemplate; // the type of this is my template column
```

However, if I then postback on this page (asking for new data, or the same to be populated in the grid), all the events are fired and my columns are added in OnInit, but when I get to PreRender the ItemTemplate of the cell has null for the ItemTemplate property (even though OnInit has definitely added this column and it does display as an empty cell with none of the controls added in OnInit).  It's as if some event has not fired which would set the TemplateField to my template on the postback.

I've tried forcing a DataBind but this does not work.  I've also tried using InstantiateIn to populate/modify the column but this isnt even fired on the postback, even though I can see the column template is added (constructor invoked for the template).

Really very confused about how this is supposed to work...

**UPDATE 1**

To clarify: the InstantiateIn is called on first page load, but not on any postbacks.  BUT! the column IS added.  E.g. if i had 5 cols, then added my template in the GV in OnInit.  It's there every time, it's created but is not my template field type after the first load.

Comment: are you not using a datatable to bind the grid view?

Comment: there is a datasource which is used when binding the data.  After the databinding i would expect the template field which was added as a new column to have the InstantiateIn method called (which it is on the first load of the page), on postbacks though the InstantiateIn method is not called (another symptom/clue) and also the cell which should contain this template field, does not.